# How to limit concurrent connections on Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase

it might be not the place, but in Firebase's site it seems that it is acceptable to ask here.
In the free plan of them, where you are limited to 100 devices connected at the same time, is it when you use the `AddValueEventListener ()` function, which make you still updated realtime.

what I want to do is just to request some data from the DB, and have users scrolling and getting more information and data when they want. I do it just to learn development, but in what I assume I will reach the 100 Devices/Users fast.

If I use the `AddListenerForSingleEventValue ()` which actually Detach the listener after the first call, will it be possible to have more then 100 devices using my app with the data provided by the application?
do they mean in the site that I cannot have more then 100 listeneres at the same time? (and if I detach it it's fine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do it just to learn development, but in what I assume I will reach the 100 Devices/Users fast.

You'd be surprised about that. Most developers vastly over-estimate the number of *concurrent* users they will get. But if you do get them, that'd be a good problem to have. :-)

Calling `addListenerForSingleEventValue()` will remove the listener after the first value, but it will not close the connection. To programmatically close the connection, call `Firebase.goOffline()` and then `Firebase.goOnline()` again.

Comment: Thank you. does it mean that whenever I make a new FireBase reference I will make it go offline when I finish requesting the data? 
I think that in this solution is just fine, cause I am making just some note-sharing app for practice. (when I click a note, I'll have to make a new firebase ref when I start the new actvitiy, and then go off line again).
It is a good solution since if I'll have really a lot of users, I'll be fine with upgrading my plan. but not now. Thank you again.