# Does Firebase ValueEventListener call succeeds when there are more than 100 live connection in free plan?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My app is using Firebase and there are almost 200 users live at the a given time. Most of the users are complaining that the data doesn't load. I was using ChildEventListener for obtaining the data which keep the connection alive and reflects live changes. There is a limit of 100 connections in the free plan. I guess that is the reason my data is not loading at times. After reading the doc I found another way to read data using ValueEventListener. Below is the code I'm currently using

```
      public void getImages() {
        Query imagesQuery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("englishDps").child(mChildName).orderByKey().limitToLast(21);

        ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Image image = dataSnapshot.getValue(Image.class);
                image.setNodeKey(dataSnapshot.getKey());

                mTempImages.add(image);
                if (mTempImages.size() == 21) {
                    mLastKey = mTempImages.get(0).getNodeKey();
                    Collections.reverse(mTempImages);
                    mTempImages.remove(mTempImages.size() - 1);
                    mImages.addAll(mTempImages);
                    setAdapter();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                if (isAdded()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Problem loading more images...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        };

        ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for(DataSnapshot imageSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    Image image = imageSnapshot.getValue(Image.class);
                    image.setNodeKey(imageSnapshot.getKey());

                    mTempImages.add(image);
                    if (mTempImages.size() == 21) {
                        mLastKey = mTempImages.get(0).getNodeKey();
                        Collections.reverse(mTempImages);
                        mTempImages.remove(mTempImages.size() - 1);
                        mImages.addAll(mTempImages);
                        setAdapter();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };

//        imagesQuery.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
//        imagesQuery.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
        imagesQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
    }
```

According to the docs

> "While using a ChildEventListener is the recommended way to read lists
>   of data, there are situations where attaching a ValueEventListener to
>   a list reference is useful.
>
> Attaching a ValueEventListener to a list of data will return the
>   entire list of data as a single DataSnapshot, which you can then loop
>   over to access individual children.
>
> Even when there is only a single match for the query, the snapshot is
>   still a list; it just contains a single item. To access the item, you
>   need to loop over the result:.
>
> **This pattern can be useful when you want to fetch all children of a list in a single operation, rather than listening for additional
>   onChildAdded events.**"

I was thinking this will solve the data loading problem but my previous version of the app will still keep using live connection and I'm still seeing random success and failures for data load call in new version of the app with more than 150+ users live right now on old version of the app. What will happen if the old version of the app opens more than 100 connection and the new version of the app tries to load data ? i.e. if 100 connections in the free plan are used will a query with

```
imagesQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

succeed or fail ?

Comment: what are the image file restrictions?  e.g. for read and write

Comment: I'm just storing the image urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an Android app first uses the Firebase Database SDK, it makes a connection to the Firebase servers. If there are at that moment already as many connection as are allowed to your database, the new connection will be rejected. The type of listener has no influence on this.

For a lot of discussions covering this already, see [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+connection+limit). Some good ones:

- [Limitation of free plan in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27501794/limitation-of-free-plan-in-firebase/27626082#27626082)
- [How the Connection is calculated in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19466522/how-the-connection-is-calculated-in-firebase/20663071#20663071)
- [When are new connections allowed after limit of 100 concurrent connection is reached in firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786933/when-are-new-connections-allowed-after-limit-of-100-concurrent-connection-is-rea)
- [How exactly are concurrent users determined for a Firebase app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307341/how-exactly-are-concurrent-users-determined-for-a-firebase-app)
- [How to limit concurrent connections on Firebase Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35521267/how-to-limit-concurrent-connections-on-firebase-android)

Comment: Took the paid plan :D

Answer (score 1):

Having looked at your code. I recommend inserting a closing connection once the read of images from json are completed. In the free package there is a limit of connections so once they read the images, they're technically still connected.

Looking at your Datasnapshot, they don't do anything but still querying the Firebase. I also recommend look into indexing too.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data